# forward declaration at class template specialisation

Tags: c++, templates

Is the following forward declaration, at the class template specialisation stage, legal C++ code?

```
template<typename>
struct Basic
{};

template<>
struct Basic<struct Foo> //<-- Fwd declaration?
{};

struct Foo
{
    Basic<Foo> m_a;
};

int main()
{
    Foo test;
}
```

It [does compile](http://rextester.com/NLJS2787), but I'm not sure if it's legal

Comment: Did you try compiling it? Did the compiler accept it?

Comment: As an example of where this is used in real code, see Spirit X3. [This part of the documentation](https://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html) does it (with `x3::rule<class employee, ...>`)

Comment: @R Sahu Of course I did.. I wouldn't post a question like this without trying it first. The question is whether or not it's legal, not if it works. Here's the code: http://rextester.com/NLJS2787

Comment: Yes, it is legal C++ and it's not the only place you can do this.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos, that's additional information that I think you should add it to the post.

Comment: @Justin Interestingly enough, at the doc you sent, it is used as a template argument, not parameter. Didn't know you could do this.

Comment: @DeiDei Cool. Where did you get this from? Can you share a link please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<>
struct Basic<struct Foo>
{};
```

is legal.

From [C++11 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.name#2):

> A class declaration introduces the class name into the scope where it is declared and hides any class, variable, function, or other declaration of that name in an enclosing scope.

Comment: @R Sahu Thanks! That's what I was looking for! If the standard says so, that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is legal C++ and it does forward declare `struct Foo`.

You can also do this in function declarations:

```
void fun(struct foo);

struct foo {};

void fun(struct foo) {}
```

or with pointers.

```
struct foo* pointer;
struct foo {};
```

Basically anywhere where a complete type is not required. (Works with `class` as well.)